# EC2 VM import: VirtualBox

Tags: virtualization, amazon-ec2, virtualbox, virtual-machines, import

I would like to know if it's currently possible to import a virtualbox vm on the ec2 cloud, I have tried with a virtualbox vmdk but it did not succed. Apparently it is designed for VMware's vmdk files.

Is there a trick I could use to convert my instance and import it on amazon?

Thanks !

Answer (score 6):

Alternatively there's this:

http://www.ioncannon.net/system-administration/1246/converting-from-virtualbox-or-vmware-to-ec2-now-easier-than-ever/

which sounds like if you just have an EC2 compatible kernel...

Answer (score 2):

There is the standalone [vmware converter](http://downloads.vmware.com/d/info/datacenter_downloads/vmware_vcenter_converter_standalone/4_0) that will convert between different virtual machine formats.

You may also want to read [this](http://thewebfellas.com/blog/2008/9/1/creating-an-new-ec2-ami-from-within-vmware-or-from-vmdk-files) which gives information on how to convert from vmware images to ec2 AMIs

Or do it directly with [this](http://www.ioncannon.net/system-administration/1246/converting-from-virtualbox-or-vmware-to-ec2-now-easier-than-ever/)

Answer (score 0):

There are some options to upload virtual box based VMs.

One of them is to use live capture tools. Run it from your guest machine to form an Amazon compatible image. The tool to use highly depends on your guest OS:

- For Windows, you could use [this tool I am associated with](http://www.migrate2iaas.com/)
- For Linux, guys already mentioned [this great
  post](http://www.ioncannon.net/system-administration/1246/converting-from-virtualbox-or-vmware-to-ec2-now-easier-than-ever/)

Unfortunately, Amazon EC2 cloud doesn't support more OS types. Try other cloud vendors like CloudSigma or ElasticHosts to run non-standard Windows Servers editions (like Storage Server) or other "geeky" OS like FreeBSD.

Answer (score 0):

Many years have passed since this answer was posted, but I thought I would add an answer in case anyone ends up here.

AWS now supports uploading VMDKs to S3 and booting it up into an EC2 instance...

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vm-import/latest/userguide/vmimport-instance-import.html